# Imported python class instance inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, locust

Currently I'm inheriting from an external class and importing another one locally:

```
from locust.contrib.fasthttp import FastHttpUser
from local_helper import TaskDetails

class User_1(FastHttpUser):

        @task
        def iteration_task(self):
            self.client.get(url)
```

I want to offload `self.client.get(url)` to `TaskDetails`,

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
td = TaskDetails()

class User_1(FastHttpUser):

        @task
        td.client_get(url) # with included FastHttpUser methods from User_1 class
```

is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Can you show the code you want to do (like where do you want to put `td = TaskDetails()` for example) and describe what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: sorry if it's unclear, edited for clarity

Comment: I still don't think I understand what you want to do. You want a method of an external class `TaskDetails` to be called from inside an instance of `User_1` and call the `client.get` method from the class `FastHttpUser`? Can you give us a [example]?